# Deploying smart contract on Testrpc with Truffle

Tags: truffle, contract-deployment

I followed this tutorial(read point 2 and 3)[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IkZB.jpg): https://blog.zeppelin.solutions/the-hitchhikers-guide-to-smart-contracts-in-ethereum-848f08001f05 to create and deploy a simple smart contract, but at this point:

$ truffle console

// get the deployed version of our contract

truffle(default)> var poe = ProofOfExistence1.deployed()

// and print its address

truffle(default)> console.log(poe.address)
0x3d3bce79cccc331e9e095e8985def13651a86004

I can't print the address..
[[image]]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of recent versions of truffle `deployed()` now returns a promise, so try something like:

```
var poe;
ProofOfExistence1
  .deployed()
  .then(function(result){ 
    poe = result; 
    console.log(poe.address);
  });
```

Comment: Perfect! It works now..thank you!
  Just another (dumb) question: If I want to execute a file,instead of writing the code, line by line, in the truffle console,how do I do it?

Comment: And also can you suggest me an updated truffle tutorial??

Comment: Beyond the Truffle docs I don't have a good suggestion for an up-to-date tutorial but on a quick glance at the one you linked I don't think much has changed since apart from things that used to return values now returning promises.

Comment: the tutorial at http://truffleframework.com/tutorials/robust-smart-contracts-with-openzeppelin is pretty decent and more recent